# Linking nginx config with installing

Tags: shell, web, nginx, debian

I am trying to install nginx with a shell script but it seems like I have made a mistake:

```
# INSTALL NGINX
apt-get install nginx
# LINK CONFIGURATION FILE
ln -fs /etc/configuration/nginx/nginx/app.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/app
ln -fs /etc/configuration/nginx/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
# RESTART
service nginx restart
```

My configuration for my app.conf is as such:

```
server { 
    listen 80; 
    root /home/deploy/project123; 
    server_name www.project123.com;
    location / { try_files $uri @app; }
    location @app {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/uwsgi.sock;
    }
}
```

My nginx.conf is such:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 1;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
      worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
      include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
      access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
      include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
      include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

My code is in: `/home/deploy/project123`

When I visit the site I get a 404 as if nothing is running. Can anyone tell me what I have done wrong please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ln -fs /etc/configuration/nginx/nginx/app.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/app
```

You need to link it to sites-enabled and not available - and it will probably work for you.

I would also not change the name of the conf-file, for clarity:

```
ln -fs /etc/configuration/nginx/nginx/app.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

would make it work

Looks like you are doing some configuration management of your own, have you check out puppet, chef, cfengine, saltstack?